# loop and array confusion: counter variable?

Tags: c++

What is the value of total after the following loops complete?

```
int a[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
```

a.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { total = total + a[i];}
```

b.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i=i+2) { total = total + a[i];}
```

c.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i=i+2) { total = total + a[i];}
```

d.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) { total = total + a[i];}
```

e.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i=2 * i) { total = total + a[i];}
```

f.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) { total = total + a[i];}
```

g.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i=i - 2) { total = total + a[i];}
```

h.

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { total = a[i] – total;}
```

Looking for an explanation of HOW you got the total of just ONE of these. I need to understand it and do it for myself.

When I stuck a into the program I got `45`, but WHY. How do I manually add this?
is a. `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9`? I mean that does equal 45 but for b. I do not understand what `i=i+2` means! I thought it mean that the loop completes and then `i=2` (was `i=0`) and for the third time it would be `i=4` and so on and of course it would keep going until `i=8` since adding 2 more would be 10 and the loop would exit at that point.

Please anyone care to explain. I'm looking to LEARN, not just get answer. I don't understand what they want with i.

Comment: The way to understand what the program is doing is to write the variables down on a piece of paper, and then pretend you're the computer executing the code.

Comment: What do you mean by _I do not understand what i=1+2 means_? That's not in any of the codes. Do you mean `i=i+2`?

Comment: This doesn't really fit Stack Overflow. If you want to learn how ``for`` loops work, check out [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/), for example. By introducing the array ``a``, you added more complexity, which seems sub-optimal for understanding loops.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do but I have no idea if I am doing it right. like with b., dos i=i+2 mean after the loop goes through 2 is added to i? I don't know how to actually read this in relation to the array.

Comment: I understand loops but the array itself is what I don't understand I don't get how I would get the total amount what is being added or multiplied or whatever by what.

Comment: Yes, `i = i + 2` means that 2 is added to `i`. What else would it mean?

Comment: It's just an ordinary assignment. `i = <expression>` means that you calculate the value of the expression, and store the result in `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first one, and I'll let you try the others yourself.

```
int a[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
```

That is your main array. You can think of it as a list with 10 slots. 
In slot 0, 1 is stored. In slot 1, 2 is stored. In slot 10, 0 is stored.
It is important to remember than an array starts with 0, and not 1.

If you want what's in the array slot number 5 you can write:

```
a[5];
```

For example:

```
int sum = a[5];
```

Now sum equals to what is in slot 5 of the array. 
Now, if you write:

```
int sum = a[5] + a[2];
```

That would result in sum equaling 9.

A for-loop that is built like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

first initializes i to 0.

```
int i = 0;
```

Then loops whats inside it's brackets until

```
i < 10;
```

is not true.

The

```
i++
```

Simply adds 1 to i each time the loop iterates.

So, back to the first case.

```
int a[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    total = total + a[i];
}
```

In the first iteration, i = 0.

```
total = total + a[0];
```

Which is 1. In the second iteration, i = 1.

```
total = total + a[1];
```

total is already 1. So it's 1 + (what is in the second slot of the array), which is 2.
1+2 = 3.

```
total = total + a[2];
```

total is already 3. So it's 3 + (what is in the third slot of the array), which is 3.
3+3 = 6.

It is important to remember that an array starts with 0.

I hope you can do the rest yourself, and if you can't, I can help you out!

Comment: Jasmin your explanation was the most helpful. SO for b I am adding 2 to i meaning the loop is only repeating a total of 5 times, correct, so would that make the total 15?

Comment: From this explanation I am also understanding that  c. would be 15 too.

Comment: B:
i starts out as 0. And is calculated each loop with: i=i+2.
in iteration 1, i = 0.
in iteration 2, i = 0+2.
in iteration 3, i = 2+2.
in iteration 4, i = 4+2.
in iteration 5, i = 6+2.
in iteration 6, i = 8+10

1+3+5+7+9 = 25.

Sorry for badly built text, but I can't edit it any nicer.

Comment: Oh I understand, i applies to position in the array itself. This was what I was misunderstanding. So then C. would be 2+4+6+8+0 = 20?

Comment: but then with d there isn't 10 values in this case it stops at 0, the total being 42?
I'm assuming it would just stop there?
Edit: my book says "Because 100
is an invalid subscript, the program will write data beyond the array s boundaries" but what does that exactly mean.

Comment: You are fully right until 42. But then i = 10, but remember, an array starts with index 0, not 1. And since this array only contains 10 numbers, you are "out of boundaries".

Comment: |n|n|n|n|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0|n|n|n|n|n

At the end you try to add n to 42. n doesn't contain a number.

Comment: Okay I understand. Okay I think this is my last question as I am working through them. d is i= i*2 but i is = 0. So would these repeat infinitely or would it stop at 9? I don't see how this could work.

Comment: If you mean e and not d, then you are indeed right!

Comment: g. for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { a[i + 5] = a[i]; }

For this I asked for the values of the array values, so this would only use 0,1,2,3,4 (1,2,3,4,5) in which it woud add 0+5, 1+5 and so on so like i[4] =10?

Answer (score 0):

You have a loop, for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

That means i will start at 0 and go all the way up to 9... which is i < 10 (less than 10)

Inside the loop you are adding... total = total + a[i]

What you are adding is the values in your array... int a[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};

So for a. you are adding all of them... including the last value in your array, 0.

a[0] = 1
a[1] = 2
etc.

In the second example you have for (int i = 0; i < 10; i=i+2)

This means the loop value i will start at 0, then go 2, 4, 6 etc. so you will be adding  a[0], a[2], a[4] etc. all the way up to a[8]

In the more complex examples you have a different starting value for your loop...

for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)... this will start at 2 instead of 0... and also will INCLUDE 10, because you have a "less than or equal to" instead of just a less than.

In other loops you have i--... this means you value of i will decrease by one instead of increase by 1 in the loop.

Hopefully that's enough to get you going?